# I cannot send an email using curl and c++

Tags: c++, email, curl

im trying to send an email with curl and c++ just like [this example](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mail.html) but when i execute the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>


int main()
{   
    int a;
    char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE] = {0};
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode res;
    struct upload_status upload_ctx = { 0 };
    if(curl)
    {   
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, "");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, "");
        
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payload_source);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &upload_ctx);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
        
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "D:\\MinGW\\cacert.pem");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    check_errors(res, errbuf);

    return 0;
}
```

i get this error:

```
curl_easy_perform() failed: Failed sending data to the peer

libcurl: (55) MAIL failed: 530
```

I deleted most of the code because i couldn't post the question but the rest is in the example.

Comment: The 530 error means the mail server could not authenticate you.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server

Comment: In the old days (before spam) SMTP servers were trusting and allowed anybody to connect and send mail. Nowadays (in the modern world) SMTP servers are locked down tight (you don't want your SMTP server to be abused by spammers) so the example is not going to work with any comercial SMTP servers. You could probably get away with doing this if you set up your own SMTP server (docker image) but your SMTP server would not be able to send any outgoing mail (as no other server would trust you). If you want to send e-mail your best bet is to learn the google gmail API (which uses a REST not SMTP).

Comment: i have already been able to  send an email but it is in fact marked as spam.

Comment: Please post an answer bellow on what you did so others can learn from your question.

Comment: Related: https://curl.se/mail/lib-2014-06/0087.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem i had in my code was that i thought that by using:
`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, "myemail@example.com");` i was specifyng the username, which was in fact, an error.

To specify the username libcurl has another option:
`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "myemail@example.com");`